# react nested routes default path blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How can I make the parent path render a default outlet in react router v6 nested routes?
As you can see in the example I want to make `"/dashboard"` path take me to `"/dashboard/home"` by default.

For now it's just rendering a blank screen in the `Outlet`.

```
<Route path={"dashboard"} element={<Dashboard />}>
  <Route path={"home"} element={<Home />} />        
  <Route path={"users"} element={<Users />} />        
</Route>
```

Comment: What `Outlet` are you referring to? Can you clarify what you mean by "render a default outlet"? Is `"users"` supposed to be a nested route from `"home"` or are the they just missing closing tags? Can you edit to include all relevant code you are using? See [mcve].

Comment: yeah sorry i closed the tags now . the outlet is inside dashboard and home and users are both children of dashboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render an [Index route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#index-routes) to render some content when the path equals that of the parent route.

Example:

```
<Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />}> // "/dashboard/*"
  <Route index element={/* some content */} />   // "/dashboard"
  <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />       // "/dashboard/home"
  <Route path="users" element={<Users />} />     // "/dashboard/users"
</Route>
```

If you want a *specific* nested route to be a "default" then either render it again as the index route *or* render a redirect to it.

Examples:

```
<Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />}>
  <Route index element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="users" element={<Users />} />
</Route>
```

or

```
<Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />}>
  <Route index element={<Navigate to="home" replace />} />
  <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="users" element={<Users />} />
</Route>
```